# What is this folded paper text effect called and how do I achieve it in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, photoshop-effects, style-identification

I am struggling to get this effect in Photoshop, but I am also unaware of what its technical name is. Can somebody please let me know what the name of the the effect that is being used below, that would be of great use to me!

[image]

Comment: This is a paper folding font. And some call it Origami typeface.

Comment: Hi James, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. [Let me Google this for you](https://www.google.nl/search?q=paper+foldin+letter+effect+photoshop&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=WV6-VISjEoPzUqCUhLAG#q=paper+folding+letter+effect+photoshop&spell=1). If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: @hsawires Is there a plug-in or this is already available in PS?

Comment: Sorry, but you'll just have to do the work on this one. Afaik, there's no plugin or tool that could do this for you. The Google link in my previous comment gives ample tutorials and instructions.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, this turned out great for me!